# Java doesn't know how to multiply? What?

Tags: java, decimal, multiplication

So I'm making a cookie clicker clone in java (shame on me) and for one thing, I need the double to increase by .1 for each cursor you own. The code looks like this (cookies is a double, and all other values are ints):

```
cookies = cookies + (cursors*.1+grandmas/2+farms*4+factories*10);
```

however, when this outputs, it outputs numbers like 2.399999999999999 instead of 2.4. What is going on?

Comment: Read this: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Try `cursors/10.0` instead of `cursors*0.1`  This will reduce the error.

Comment: And it has *nothing* to do with java. This is *general* behavior for all languages that use IEEE floating point math. Because thats how IEEE math *works*, be it C/C++/Java/.net whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is double's precision. You could use

```
cookies = Math.round( cookies * 100.0 ) / 100.0;
```